# Protractor locator for formControlName

Tags: angular, protractor

I'm using model based forms where my form looks like:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
  <input type="text" formControlName="username">
  <input type="password" formControlName="password">
  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I want to write a protractor spec to test the login.  I would *like* to do something like the following in my spec:

```
    element(by.formControlName('username')).sendKeys('test@example.com');
```

This obviously doesn't work so is there a way to locate by form controls or am I resigned to the fact that I have to put a class or ID on the input fields?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can write a rather simple *CSS selector*:

```
element(by.css("input[formControlName=username]")).sendKeys('test@example.com');
```

---

Note that if you need to do this often, you can always define a reusable [*custom locator*](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.addLocator):

```
by.addLocator('formControlName', function(value, opt_parentElement, opt_rootSelector) {
  var using = opt_parentElement || document;

  return using.querySelectorAll('[formControlName="' + value +'"]');
});
```

Usage:

```
element(by.formControlName('username')).sendKeys('test@example.com');
```

Comment: The by.css works, thanks.  Where would I put the addLocator if I want to use it globally in my application?

Comment: @MarkKenny great, you should put the `by.addLocator` into `onPrepare()` function in your protractor config..

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  Maybe I'm too new to protractor but I just copy/paste'd the `by.addLocator` code snippet into my onPrepare function and it just causes everything to hang.  Perhaps a config issue somewhere else.  When I figure it out I'll post

Comment: It appears that it's an issue with Chrome and the Chrome driver.  Works if I switch to Firefox.  Chrome driver v2.22 and Chrome v49 are apparently compatible but when I run my tests Chrome hangs.